# PHP Wrong Parameters

Tags: php, parameters

I'm trying to make a registration page but PHP is telling me that I have the wrong parameters, which doesn't make sense unless I need to add a parameter for the auto-incremental primary ID key.

Here's my SQL query call:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (username, password, fname, lname, email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s, '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($username),
        mysql_real_escape_string($password),
        mysql_real_escape_string($first),
        mysql_real_escape_string($last),
        mysql_real_escape_string($email)) or die(mysql_error());
```

It gives me the wrong paramater count on the last line in this code block. Any ideas? I copied and pasted the row-names straight from my database.

my table is as follows:

```
id - int(11) - auto-incrementing
username - varchar(20)
password - varchar(20)
fname - varchar(35) 
lname - varchar(35)
email - varchar(254)
```

Comment: Next time, include the error message verbatim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have formatted the SQL query as a `sprintf()` call, but don't call `sprintf()`

```
mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO Users (username, password, fname, lname, email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password),
            mysql_real_escape_string($first),
            mysql_real_escape_string($last),
            mysql_real_escape_string($email))) or die(mysql_error());
  // also note some parentheses out of place ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: There were no parentheses out of place. And he formatted the PHP function call that way, not the SQL query.

Comment: :S this might be a whole other question, but I'm getting an "error near email@email.com" - does varchar accept the '@' symbol?

Comment: @Tomalak As the intended `sprintf()` call there were.  The `mysql_query()` was closed, the closing `)` for `sprintf()` must be added, and I thought there was an extra closing `)` after the `die()` originally but it was edited out.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee There was another missing quote on the second to last `%s`. Edited in my answer

Comment: @Michael: There should be no closing `)` for `sprintf()` if there is no `sprintf()` :)

Comment: Yeah I editted the original problem when I saw the parentheses were out of place :S sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

It's PHP that's telling you off about parameters, not MySQL.

You've tried to use `mysql_query` like `sprintf`, which it is not. `mysql_query` accepts an optional database resource identifier, and the query string. Two parameters. That is all.

If you *do* want to use `sprintf`, then go for it:

```
mysql_query(
   sprintf(
      "INSERT INTO Users (username, password, fname, lname, email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s, '%s')",
      mysql_real_escape_string($username),
      mysql_real_escape_string($password),
      mysql_real_escape_string($first),
      mysql_real_escape_string($last),
      mysql_real_escape_string($email)
   )
) or die(mysql_error());
```

But remember that the first argument to `mysql_query` is just a string. No magic.

Comment: Correct, the query never reaches the MySQL in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query(
    sprintf("INSERT INTO Users (username, password, fname, lname, email) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s, '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($username),
    mysql_real_escape_string($password),
    mysql_real_escape_string($first),
    mysql_real_escape_string($last),
    mysql_real_escape_string($email)))

or die(mysql_error()); // sprintf to build a final string of your query by given format and "or die statement" is outside the mysql_query function call.
```

Comment: Yes but it can work with one also. It is not needed to pass the connection.

Comment: @Mike: He's only passing it one.

Comment: @Rolice: Better indentation would have avoided Mike's confusion.

Comment: Oh darn, I missed the sprintf there :P

Comment: Yes I use a new line and additional identation for the arguments, it seems readable to me, when lot of arguments are passed. It should looks good in editor. Also the or die is on new line to show its independence from the call of mysql_query. :D